# Getting rid of the $(n-1)$th terms of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Quadratics, cubics and quartics are solvable using a substitution like $x=y+k$, where $k$ is usually the root of the $(n-1)$th derivative of the polynomial. ($n$ is the degree of the polynomial.)
This makes the $(n-1)$th term cancels, rendering a simpler, solvable equation.

Does this manipulation stop at quintics?